# Advanced search doesn't return expected results when using min & max (dates) together?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, search

I want to use the Advanced Search API to get the same results as [the Stack Overflow site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]%20vm%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2015-11-08..2015-11-10).
With it, I can see new questions on 11/10/2015.

When I tried to craft a query using the Advanced Search API, it returns no questions on 11/10/2015:

[/2.2/search/advanced?min=1446940800&max=1447113600&body=vm&tagged=sql-server](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&min=2015-11-08&max=2015-11-10&sort=activity&body=vm&tagged=sql-server&filter=!9YdnSQVoS&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Am I using the Advanced Search API in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date parameters are in unix epoch time and `1447113600` is 2015-11-10, 00:00:00.
So any questions posted on Nov 10th actually happened after that.

When **searching for date ranges**, you usually want to **increment the end-date** (`max` in this case) **by one full day**.

For example, if you want items from 12-12-2012 to 12-13-2012, you would use `max=1355443200` (The equivalent of 12 AM on 12-14-2012).

When you take this into account, then:

[/2.2/search/advanced?min=1446940800&max=1447200000&body=vm&tagged=sql-server](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&min=2015-11-08&max=2015-11-11&sort=creation&body=vm&tagged=sql-server&filter=!9YdnSQVoS&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Returns the 3 questions you expect.

See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6172/7653) for more details.

---

PS:  For your apparent task, you probably want `sort=creation` rather that `sort=activity`.