# bad_parameter when using key with todate?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, api-key, date

I'm having trouble using my API key with the `todate` parameter. My query works fine with `todate`:

```
$ curl -s "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?todate=2015-07-21&site=stackoverflow&tagged=abap&filter=total" | gunzip
{"total":830}
```

And it works fine with my API key if I remove `todate`:

```
$ curl -s "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?site=stackoverflow&tagged=abap&filter=total&key=$mykey" | gunzip
{"total":1144}
```

But for some reason I can't use both:

```
$ curl -s "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?todate=2015-07-21&site=stackoverflow&tagged=abap&filter=total&key=$mykey" | gunzip
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"todate","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

From [the *Date Formats* doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates):

> For convenience when doing ad-hoc queries **without a key** an alternative date format is accepted: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, where the hour, minute, and second values are optional.
>   **Applications should not ship using this date format (as all applications should ship with a key), it is provided just to ease rapid development.**

(Emphasis mine)

So you need to specify dates in *unix epoch time*. Which means for `2015-07-21` you would use:

```
/2.2/search/advanced?todate=1437436800&site=stackoverflow&tagged=abap&filter=total&key=$mykey
```

EXCEPT: [You probably want results to 2015-07-21 *inclusive*](https://stackapps.com/a/6172/7653), in which case your `todate` should be `1437523200` -- which corresponds to midnight (UTC) of 2015-07-22 -- that is the very end of 2015-07-21.